# Problems with multi-threading windows in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, window

I'm opening av new WPF-window in an new thread like [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/suchit_84/creating-wpf-windows-on-dedicated-threads/):

```
private void OnCreateNewWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        w.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run(); 
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    }
}
```

The problem is it gets stuck on the Show-method (without showing a window) and never reaches Dispatcher.Run.

When checking the threads and call-stacks I can see two threads, Main and my new window-thread. The callstack of the window-thread is at the following frame:

> PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object
>   sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e,
>   System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute) + 0x1c0 bytes

When trying modifications to the code I once managed to get an exception with the message:

> Cannot use a DependencyObject that belongs to a different thread than
>   its parent Freezable.

I get a feeling this has something to do with access to resources owned by the main thread that's not frozen. In this app I have a lot of generic styles and resources, brushes etc but I'm trying to avoid using them in this specific dialog by putting the following in the constructor of the window:

> InheritanceBehavior = InheritanceBehavior.SkipAllNow;

But this does not seem to be enough. Somehow, some unallowed resource seem to be accessed anyway.

The frame with FindCommandBinding hints that it could be a problem with a command-binding. But this dialog has no command-bindings.

Are resources like brushes implicitly frozen if they are defined in a resource-dictionary? If not, how do I freeze them explicitly in a simple way? There are hundreds of brushes. But this may not be the problem here.

Any other ideas?

Comment: As you already assumed this is most certainly a problem with resources shared between the two dispatcher threads. Resources like brushes are not implicitly frozen. However you may set `PresentationOptions:Freeze="True"` on Freezable objects declared in XAML. See the *Freezing from Markup* section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx).

Comment: Why create a new thread anyway?

Comment: I've tried freezing all my brushes but that didn't help. In any case I think they shouldnt be loaded when using SkipAllNow. Weird.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use Dispatcher.Invoke or BegingInvoke method to executing the creation of winodw object and calling show method. Worker thread can not call or update the control.

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => new Thread(() =>     { Window1 w = new Window1();         w.Show();})
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? I have one dispatcher (with a thread) and I'm creating a new thread from this one. I don't need to invoke the thread creation. The window and the show-method is called within this new dispatcher/thread. Why do I need using invoke here?

Comment: @pchajer Read [this](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/11/28/launching-a-wpf-window-in-a-separate-thread-part-1/).

Comment: No invoke there? But the SetSynchronizationContext was new to me. I tried that but it didn't help.